# throttling based on authentication class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

in DRF docs there is a page about [throttling](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/throttling/) api requests, I wanted to create a custom throttle class, to make something like twitter api (in twitter api direct user/passwords can make less requests/min compared to oauth requests)

my problem is how to find out which authentication class was used in current request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the code I saw that DRF [stores the authenticator instance](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/request.py#L324) on the request. So i guess you can do something like:

```
if type(request._authenticator).__name__ == "TokenAuthentication":
```

or something like that

Hope this helps